# Why does IntelliJ Idea not autocomplete the MediaType enum inside a jersey resource @Consumes or @Produces annotation?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, jersey

This seems like an awfully strange and specific bug or maybe some obtuse setting I am not setting.

For @Path the value that is expected is String and @Produces\@Consumes expects a String[] so no huge difference there I would think.

References :
[@Path](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/ws/rs/Path.html) [@Consumes](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/ws/rs/Consumes.html) [@Produces](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/ws/rs/Produces.html)

Updated :

This is what I want...
[image]

This is what it is giving me..

[image]

Comment: Are you talking about [this](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19776-01/820-4867/ggqqr/) annotation? Its `value` element doesn't take an `enum` value, it takes a `String[]`.

Comment: What's the version of IntelliJ IDEA? What is your operating system?

Comment: Sotirios: Wouldn't the compiler convert the ENUM to a String? I have no problem entering the enum manually. Zero errors, zero complaints.. it just won't auto-complete for me.

Comment: engineer: I am using Idea 15 and OS X El Capitan

Comment: Please use `@username` to reply. We don't get notifications otherwise. No, the compiler doesn't convert an `enum` value to a `String` value. You must not be doing what you're telling us or you're using a different `@Consumes` and `@Produces` annotation.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Sorry. I am using the annotation as follows `@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)` which works perfectly fine. But when I type `MediaType.` the only options for the autocomplete are the actual string values.

Comment: `MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON` references a `String` value. The IDE will only suggest the `String` values because `@Consumes` and `@Produces` only take `String` values.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Because at this point I must seem like I'm a tool, I have attached 2 images. `@Path` and `@Consumes` and `@Produces` accept strings. The difference here is that `@Produces` and `@Consumes` take string arrays. But a single string is valid as you can see the IDE does not complain.

Comment: I'm really confused as to what your question is.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I was simply wondering if this was an IntelliJ bug or if there was a setting in IntelliJ that I was missing. I am fairly new to IntelliJ and there seems to be settings for everything.

Comment: There is no bug here. The annotation expects `String` values and the IDE shows you `String` values.

Comment: There is definitely a bug here with Intellij autocomplete on some annotations - I suggest you submit a support ticket to the Jetbrains crew, they might be able to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I submitted a ticket to intellij and it is a bug.

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-127214